# How do I stop the facebook send widget from going off the screen?

Tags: css, facebook

[image: facebook share widget going off the screen]

It doesn't work on jsfiddle, only localhost due to sandboxed iframes.

CSS Code

```
.twitter-share-button {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.return iframe, .return fb-send {
    margin-top: 4px;
}
.returnhere {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 68px;
}
.return {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #3D806B;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    color: #DCDCDC;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.return iframe, .return fb-send {
    margin-top: 4px;
}
.twitter-share-button {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.return2 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #3D806B;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    color: #DCDCDC;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.return2 iframe, .return2 fb-send {
    margin-top: -3px;
}
.twitter-share-button {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#u_0_3 {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<div class="returnhere">
    <div class="return"><a href="/tellafriend" rel="shadowbox;width=611;height=453" target="_blank">Invite via email</a>

    </div>
    <div class="return2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
        <div class="fb-send" data-href="http://compesh.com" data-font="trebuchet ms"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="return" style="vertical-align: middle;"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://simplesharebuttons.com" target="_blank"><img src="graphics/fbshare.png" alt="Facebook" /></a></div> -->
    <div class="return"><a href="/newdebate">Add a debate</a>

    </div>
    <!-- initialise -->
</div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=299539706821986";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I can't style it with CSS.

```
#u_0_3{
      background-color: yellow !important;
      left: -200px;
}
```

Comment: I've added the relevant code now.

Comment: This can be hard to control as the flyout is dynamically loaded so any CSS you have on page load will probably not have any affect on it. This is not a simple issue for Facebook to fix and they are committed to finding a more permanent solution as described here: https://developers.intern.facebook.com/bugs/1420124294938118/